# Fabric.js colors are changing to black in subclassed fabric.Group

Tags: fabricjs

I am trying to subclass fabric.Group and load a JSON string into it.
The problem I'm having is that the color of the fabric.Rect in the subclassed group is getting changed to black.
When I do it directly in fabric.Group it works great. 
I've been playing with variations on fromObject but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. 
The change seems to happen when I "enliven" the objects in the group.

Here is a fiddle demonstrating my problem https://jsfiddle.net/adgu/49feomm7/
Click on the "Load Group" button to see the red rect (which is correct) and the "Load Custom Group" button to see the black rect. 
The JSON is identical with the exception of the type being 'group' in one case and 'customGroup' in the other.

```
fabric.CustomGroup = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Group, {

  type: 'customGroup',

  initialize: function(objects, options) {
    options || (options = { });    
    //console.log('initialize objects', objects);
    //console.log('initialize options', options);
    this.callSuper('initialize', objects, options);    
  },

  toObject: function() {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
    });
  },

  _render: function(ctx) {
    this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
  }
});

fabric.CustomGroup.fromObject = function(object, callback) {   
   //console.log('fromObject', object);
   var _enlivenedObjects;
   fabric.util.enlivenObjects(object.objects, function (enlivenedObjects) {
      //console.log('enlivenObjects object', object);
      //console.log('enlivenObjects object.objects', object.objects);      
      //console.log('enlivenObjects enlivenedObjects', enlivenedObjects);
      delete object.objects;    
      _enlivenedObjects = enlivenedObjects;
   });
   return new fabric.CustomGroup(_enlivenedObjects, object);   
};
```

Comment: Here is someone that was having a similar problem but using plain groups (not subclassed). According to him, It was fixed in version 1.6.0. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36026471/convert-back-fabric-group-tojson-to-fabric-group?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I found a closed bug report that addressed my problem: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/3156

By adding true to the end of the initialize callSuper it started working. Like this:

```
this.callSuper('initialize', objects, options, true);
```

Comment: Although this solved my immediate problem (the fiddle started working), it also caused other issues with positioning and events.  After further reading, I think that groups are more subtle than I thought, and maybe subclassing Group was not such a good idea.  I'm continuing to research to find a simpler solution.